# Check multiple settings inside json (C#, Json)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, settings, appsettings

Im reading data from **appsettings.json** and if **value = true** then run **method**.

```
private void SeedExampleData(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
   var settings = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>(); 
   if(settings.Value.SeedEventsData)
   {
      var dataInitializer = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDataInitializer>();
          dataInitializer.SeedEventsAsync();
   }
}
```

My **appsettings.json**:

```
"app": {
    "SeedEventsData": true,
    "SeedAdvertsData": true
  }
```

My question is:

- If have couple of **Value** which I need to check how can I run **foreach** for *settings*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made research and did as below:

```
...
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

private void SeedExampleData(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  var appArray = Configuration.GetSection("app").AsEnumerable();
  foreach (var item in appArray)
  {
    //TO DO
  }
}
```

It's getting section by section.